# Options for wiring dependencies with NInject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, configuration-files, ninject

With NInject (preferably 2.0), what options do we have wrt wiring up our object dependencies in a web application?

Can they be defined in an XML configuration file?

Or does it have to be done via code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ninject doesn't have XML configuration, sorry but I can't provide a direct link (cos their site has flash elements), but here is a quotation from [ninject.org](http://ninject.org):

> **Free yourself from XML**
>
> Most other .NET dependency injection
> frameworks are designed around the use
> of XML to declare type bindings.
> Rather than forcing you to write
> cumbersome and error-prone text,
> Ninject arms you with a fluent
> interface, which lets you connect the
> pieces of your application using
> full-fledged code. This means you can
> take advantage of the features of the
> IDE and compiler, like code completion
> and type-safety.

Comment: Its amazing how they can make a negative sound like a plus.
Most other DI\Ioc allow you to use Xml or Code.

Comment: This is non-negative. The knowingly cut XML support, cos it is a maintainability pain.

Comment: I mostly use code to map my bindings but there are cases that configuration works. For debug I might want to bind IMailService to VirtualMailService but in release use SmtpMailService. Configuration files are transformed based on release environment.

Comment: Counterexample would be what if you'll need to rename any of those service implementations? You should keep this in mind and all your team members also. And for your case I would create an in-code configuration for both "release" and "debug" modes and in the configuration file I would have a settings like `"<add key="configuration-mode" value="release"/>`. This is just better.

Comment: Yep - I agree using a "configuration-mode" is probably the safest way to have different binding based on configuration.

Answer (score 10):

There is an extension for xml based configuration: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.xml

You can do a lot more powerful binding in code though.

Answer (score 4):

The problem I see with defining bindings in the code only is that you have to add reference to the dll.
You cannot change the binding without adding reference to new dll (removing reference to old one), change code and recompile.

If we had xml config I wouldn't need reference at all, and wouldn't have to recompile.
Right now I have MVC app that is using DI to pass repositories to Controllers. Nothing else then Ninject code for adding bindings uses the concrete implementations of repositories. And still I need to add reference to dll containing the implementations. For only one line of code!

Or maybe there is a possibility to achieve this using Ninject?

Answer (score 3):

What are you looking to achieve? What sort of stuff are you looking to configure? Dynamically selecting a Strategy ? Passing in Port numbers? You could offer a lot more information as to what you're thinking in order to get a better answer [that you can acccept :P].

You need to split the concerns of:

1. *known* object wiring (DI)
2. configuration - generally you'll want to split those into small focused subsets e.g. Strongly Typed config elements vs having a global pool of settings in a big pile mishmashed together a la `appSettings`
3. plugins / *unknown* object wiring (MEF?)

In the first pool, doing it in Code is just the right way and I cant think of any advantage XML would give, esp. in the context of strong names etc.